# What happens if I dont open instance of SqlConnection?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am reviewing a piece of code in a application and I came to something very strange in regard to connecting to database.

It is executing queries without opening the connection like this:

```
using (sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(connString)
{
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query,sqlConnection1);

    // ... parameters are handled here...

    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
    ds = new DataSet();
    ad.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source);
    ad.Fill(ds);
}
```

Shouldnt it fail because of connection is not open? I actually tested this in separate project and it worked.

Comment: When in doubt, read the manual.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the connection is closed, using SqlDataAdapter.Fill will open the connection
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377a8x4t.aspx

Comment: You might want to bring some of the content from that link across. Its unlikely that MSDN will go down, but the URL might change, rendering this answer less helpful.

Answer (score 3):

[Per the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/152bda9x.aspx), SqlDataAdapter will open the conenction if it isn't already open, and return it to its previous state.

> The connection object associated with the SelectCommand must be valid, but it does not need to be open. If the connection is closed before FillSchema is called, it is opened to retrieve data, then closed. If the connection is open before FillSchema is called, it remains open.

`Fill` also behaves in the same manner

Answer (score 3):

Refer [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

> The Fill method implicitly opens the Connection that the DataAdapter
>   is using if it finds that the connection is not already open. If Fill
>   opened the connection, it will also close the connection when Fill is
>   finished. This can simplify your code when dealing with a single
>   operation such as a Fill or an Update.

This means that after `da.Fill(ds, "Test");` your connection is closed by the method itself. But you need it open for the following Update (and that fails)

Answer (score 1):

From [`SqlDataAdapter.Fill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4b211hz.aspx) method;

> The Fill method retrieves rows from the data source using the SELECT
>   statement specified by an associated SelectCommand property. The
>   connection object associated with the SELECT statement must be valid,
>   **but it does not need to be open. If the connection is closed before Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data, then closed. If the
>   connection is open before Fill is called, it remains open.**

Also `FillSchema` method does same thing.